# Make two buttons hover together when mouse is over one of the buttons

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

I have two buttons in a stack pane so one smaller button is on top of another larger button.

StackPane

-----> Btn1

-----> Btn2

Ex:

[image]

When I hover over btn two, i want button one to still be in it's hover state.

When I hover over btn one, two should not be in it's hover state.

Look at how the close tab button behaves on GoogleChrome. That is what I would like to replicate.

Hovering over nothing.

[image]

Hovering over Tab (btn1) - slightly lighter.

[image]

Hovering over close btn (btn2) - btn one still slightly lighter, btn two is darker.

[image]

Is there any way to do this with CSS? Java code?

Comment: Do you already have custom CSS for the hover state for the buttons? If so, does it work if you make the selector for that CSS rule something like `#my-stack-pane:hover .button` (where `my-stack-pane` is the CSS id of the stack pane)?

Comment: @James_D thank you very much. This worked for me. I am not experienced with CSS so I didn't even know how to google this. If you answer the question I can make your answer the solution.